# Jquery cannot access array outside of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am getting a strange behavior from the following code. The following code is from ajax success, **And `console.log(positions);` inside loop works fine, But outside it gives me nothing.**

```
success: function (data) {
    var positions = [];

    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $.each(value, function (index1, value1) {
            positions.push({
                lat: value1.rider_location.lat,
                lng: value1.rider_location.lng,
            });
            //This works fine | I can get the results. But after commenting out the below line then the last `console.log(positions)` doesn't shows anything.
             console.log(positions);
        });
    });
    console.log(positions);
}
```

The `data` from the Ajax gives me the following results then i loop through it and assign the values to `positions`.

[image]

Indside the loop gives me the following results :

[image]

And outside of loop `console.log(positions)` **gives no exception as well as no results.**

Comment: It gives no exceptions because you declared an empty `positions`, so that is what it will print when you log it. Big chance that either your `data` or `value` is empty. Try logging those inside the loop.

Comment: Seems like either `data` or `value` is an empty collection. Can you show the code where those are populated?

Comment: @Ivar I have updated my question.

Comment: @NicholasTower I have updated my question.

Comment: Your data is probably not empty in this case, but that does not mean that it is an array you can loop over. Again, try to `console.log` your data before the first `$.each` and the `value` before the second. See what is inside of them.

Comment: @Ivar `data` have values, Its tested. I can get the `console.log(positions)` values inside of the loop but cannot get outside...

Comment: @Gammer With valid data your code works fine. See https://jsfiddle.net/ct015oLv/

Comment: Another fiddle showing it working fine with data that matches the application:  https://jsfiddle.net/8byd2cry/

Comment: *Exactly* where are you trying to use `console.log(positions)`?  Inside `success:` (as in the question) or somewhere else?   (ie outside `success:function(data) { `) ?

Comment: @Ivar i have updated the question code, I have a comment also above the `console.log(positions)`, The data format or anything is not wrong if it is then it should not work inside the loop.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have updated the question code and added a comment above `console.log(positions)`.

Comment: Also with a `console.log()` in the fiddle it still works fine. `console.log()` should not change anything (outside of edge cases). There is nothing wrong with the code you showed.

Comment: @Ivar I am currently testing it. Its not working outside but works inside.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question.  Can you recreate the issue within a code snippet in the question?  *There's nothing wrong with the code **as you've provided it**.*    I suspect you have already, but have a read of [mcve].

Comment: @Ivar i have updated the question again, Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @freedomn-m i have updated the question again, Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Edit question, press ctrl-M, enter html+code, click Run, edit code/run repeat until you have a script that actually demonstrates your problem, save and insert into post, let us know.

Comment: I can only *guess* that you're trying to access `positions` outside of the `success:` callback (likely even before your ajax call has started), but that's not what you've got in the code in your question, which has been shown to work correctly by two independent fiddles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not an array but an object. Using `$.each()` on it means that it will loop over all of it's properties, which is why it does not work as you expect it. You probably want to loop over `data.riders`. Also there is no other array to loop over, so the second loop should not be there:

```js
var data = {
    riders: [{
            rider_location: {
                lat: 2,
                lng: 3
            }
        },
        {
            rider_location: {
                lat: 4,
                lng: 5
            }
        }
    ]
};

var positions = [];

$.each(data.riders, function(index, value) {
    positions.push({
        lat: value.rider_location.lat,
        lng: value.rider_location.lng,
    });
});

console.log(positions);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the format of the data returned I would try:

It seems as if you're trying to loop through rider_location with the second loop, but rider_location is an object, so you can just access its properties.

```
success: function (data) {
    var positions = [];

    $.each(data.riders, function (index, value) {
           positions.push({
                lat: value.rider_location.lat,
                lng: value.rider_location.lng,
            });
    });
    console.log(positions);
}
```

PS feel free to rep me :)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`

Comment: try console.log(value) and console.log(value.rider_location), see if youre getting the correct results.